# Display Image On Text Link Hover CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, css, image, hover

Good day!
In this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Exponat/3y8vz/3/) displays pictures with their descriptions when you hover over the link. How to do with the CSS that the picture remains open and hidden when it points to another link?
HTML:

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%">
<tr>
<td><div class='link4'><a href="">tetx link 1
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ArB7hb.jpg" style="float:left; margin: 4px 4px;" />Description of the picture 1 Description of the picture 1 Description of the picture 1 Description of the picture 1 Description of the picture 1 Description of the picture 1</div>
</a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class='link4'><a href="">tetx link 2
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ArB7hb.jpg" style="float:left; margin: 4px 4px;" />Description of the picture 2 Description of the picture 2 Description of the picture 2 Description of the picture 2 Description of the picture 2 Description of the picture 2</div>
</a></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><div class='link4'><a href="">tetx link 3
<div><img src="http://i.imgur.com/ArB7hb.jpg" style="float:left; margin: 4px 4px;" />Description of the picture 3 Description of the picture 3 Description of the picture 3 Description of the picture 3 Description of the picture 3 Description of the picture 3</div>
</a></div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
a>div { display: none; }
a:hover>div { display: block; }
.link4 {margin-left:5px; margin-right:5px;}
.link4 a {display: block;}
```

Or is it only possible with Java?
In this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Exponat/n9bHF/3/) using JAVA but I do not know how to display a description. And leave the last image shown with the description until it points to no other link?

HTML/CSS:

```
<script>

function showImg(id,fn){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if(fn) el.innerHTML = '<img src="' + fn + '" />'; else el.innerHTML ='';
}

</script>

<body>

<table width="300" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onmouseover="showImg('img1','http://html.by/images/icons/icon5.gif')" onmouseout="showImg('img1','')">Href1<div id="img1"></div></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onmouseover="showImg('img2','http://html.by/images/icons/icon6.gif')" onmouseout="showImg('img2','')">Href2<div id="img2"></div></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#" onmouseover="showImg('img3','http://html.by/images/icons/icon7.gif')" onmouseout="showImg('img3','')">Href3<div id="img3"></div></a></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You are using JavaScript, not Java.  Two different languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at this [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pE5W/)

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
  <li> first item
    <div> text here text here text here text here text here text here </div>
  </li>
  <li> first item
    <div> text here text here text here text here text here text here </div>
  </li>
  <li> first item
    <div> text here text here text here text here text here text here </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li {
    border: 1px solid;
}
li div {
    display: none;
}
li:hover div {
    display: block;
}
```